# arcmap editor attribute window fill value programmatically

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, fields-attributes, vb.net

In my map I have a layer named PARCEL, when create new feature on this layer, the attribute window will open automatically. There are 2 attributes in this layer: PARCEL_ID and SUB_ID.

Since the PARCEL_ID is the left part of SUB_ID, I intend to display the PARCEL_ID value in SUB_ID field after user input the PARCEL_ID value, this is to minimize user key in wrong information.

Is there a way to do this without a customized editor tool?

[image]

I am using vb.net arcobjects 10.2.2.

**EDIT1**

The reason for use the attribute window in editor is when I tried to use update feature, it didn't work.

Actally my basic idea is after user create new feature:

(1) use max OBJECTID to identify the new created feature

(2) provided a window to ask user to input the PARCEL_ID and SUB_ID of the new created feature

(3) use feature.store to update the PARCEL_ID and SUB_ID values

But I failed to make it work. My code is like followings:

```
Private Sub GetMaxFID()
    Try
        Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument, pFLayer As IFeatureLayer
        Dim pCursor As ICursor
        pMxDoc = My.ArcMap.Application.Document

        Dim pMap As IMap
        Dim pActiveView As IActiveView

        pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
        pActiveView = pMxDoc.FocusMap

        Dim layerNum = GetIndexNumberFromLayerName(pActiveView, My.Settings.ParcelLayer)
        pFLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(layerNum)
        pCursor = pFLayer.Search(Nothing, False)

        If TypeOf pCursor Is IFeatureCursor Then
            Dim pData As IDataStatistics = New DataStatisticsClass
            pData.Field = "OBJECTID"
            pData.Cursor = pCursor
            Dim pStatResults As IStatisticsResults = pData.Statistics
            newOBJECTID = pStatResults.Maximum
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        logger.Error(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()
    Try
        Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
        Dim pMap As IMap
        Dim pActiveView As IActiveView

        pMxDoc = My.ArcMap.Application.Document
        pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
        pActiveView = pMxDoc.FocusMap

        Dim layerNum = GetIndexNumberFromLayerName(pActiveView, My.Settings.ParcelLayer)
        Dim pFLayer As IFeatureLayer

        pFLayer = pMap.Layer(layerNum)

        GetMaxFID()

        Dim featureClass As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass = pFLayer.FeatureClass

        If featureClass Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim feature As IFeature = pFLayer.FeatureClass.GetFeature(newOBJECTID)  ' is this line correct?

        If feature Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim objectIDFieldIndex As Integer = pFLayer.FeatureClass.FindField(newOBJECTID)

        feature.Value(1) = "test123"   'This line I want to set the PARCEL_ID of the new created feature. 
                                       'is it correct to use .value(1) here? what should be the value of (1) in this line? 
        feature.Value(2) = "test123-12" 'This line I want to set the SUB_ID of the new created feature. 
                                       'is it correct to use .value(2) here? what should be the value of (1) in this line? 

        feature.Store()

        'MsgBox("update finished")

    Catch ex As Exception
        logger.Error(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I believe there is something wrong with my code, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised if you could alter the interface of that window as that is a core part of the desktop editing environment. I've not tried it but you may be able to capture the "on feature change" event, pass your ID value into your sub ID field but if that updates that windows I have no idea?

EDIT:

I have done something similar in the past, the Feature Class was a file geodatabase feature class and I had set the default value to be -1 for an ID field called HERID. So when a new feature is created it is automatically given a -1 value.

Below is my **on Feature Create** procedure. I've removed most of the code for clarity but see how I search for a feature where the HERID = -1. I then have a handle on the feature just created and I too am using store to commit the changes to the fields.

```vb
Private Sub m_EditEvents_OnCreateFeature(obj As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IObject) Handles m_EditEvents.OnCreateFeature

    ' Declare objects
    Dim d As Date
    Dim pEditLayers As IEditLayers
    Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
    Dim pFeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor
    Dim pFeature As IFeature
    Dim pQueryFilter As IQueryFilter

    Try
        ' Set objects
        d = Date.Today
        pEditLayers = m_Editor
        pFeatureLayer = pEditLayers.CurrentLayer
        pQueryFilter = New QueryFilterClass
        pQueryFilter.WhereClause = "HERID = -1"
        pFeatureCursor = pFeatureLayer.Search(pQueryFilter, False)
        pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature

        If Not pFeature Is Nothing Then
                ' Must be a new feature created
                With pFeature
                    .Value(.Fields.FindField("HERID")) = HERID
                    .Value(.Fields.FindField("IsPrimary")) = 1
                    .Value(.Fields.FindField("FCD")) = d.ToShortDateString
                    .Value(.Fields.FindField("FLMD")) = d.ToShortDateString
                    .Store()
                End With
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error in m_EditEvents_OnCreateFeature")
    Finally
        ' Clean up
        pEditLayers = Nothing
        pFeatureLayer = Nothing
        pFeatureCursor = Nothing
        pFeature = Nothing
        pQueryFilter = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, are you talking about feature.store? I tried it but it not work. I have updated my question with the related code. Kindly advise me, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure that is the best way of doing it. I would use the [IEditEvents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IEditEvents_Interface/00200000009s000000/) Interface and its OnCreateFeature method which returns the actual row which you could update. There is some sample code on that page.

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, actually I am using OnCreateFeature to popup a window to ask user to fill in the attribute values of the new created feature, but failed to update the value in attribute table. You suggest use other method instead of feature.store? sorry I am stupid stuck here.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, thanks a lot for your example, tested and worked properly.